# .HTACCESS MOD_REWRITE FLat Links Issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a few problems re-writing flat links using htaccess, I have two sets of rules which independently work perfectly well but when put together have an undesirable effect.

The first section adds a trailing forward slash if one is absent and re-writes the url with a 301 divert.

The second converts all of the ‘folders’ into parameters which is then passed to php in a particular format.

We have an unknown number of folders depending on the page so wish to keep the code generic.

The problem is that although the code functionality works (i.e. php is fed the correct parameters) the url is re-written in the wrong format.

Php code:

```
<?php echo ‘<pre>’;print_r($_GET); echo ‘</pre>’;?>
```

Sample url: (removed HTTP:// as restricted to two links per question)

```
localhost/foo/bar
```

is re-written to

```
test.localhost/foo&other[]=bar/
```

with output:

```
Array
(
    [p] => foo
    [other] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
        )
)
```

If you remove the first section for the htaccess then the output is the same and the url remains:

```
localhost/foo/bar
```

HTACCESS:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

SECTION 1:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

SECTION 2:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)/?$ $1&other[]=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm confused with what you want to do and what the problem is. Can you please clarify it -- please provide 1 or 2 examples of the such URLs: how they look in browser and how you want them to be sent to PHP script (rewritten). As I understand you want `http://example.com/foo/bar` => `http://example.com/foo/bar/` => ??? (the final URL that will be sent to PHP)

Comment: I'm trying to change http://localhost/foo/bar, so a forward slash is append if needed and that when I print_r $_GET, I have an array Like ([p] => foo [other] => Array([0] => bar)). First part after the localhost becomes the the value for p and the rest is placed into the other array. Separately, the conditions/rules in the original post do work, however when they are used together the problem occurs. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these lines instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on
# Force trailing slash to be present (only if such file does not exist)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,QSA]
# Rewrite rule to real php file (only if such folder does not exist)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/$ /index.php?p=$1&other[]=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Please note, the last line will only work for URLs of this structure: `/foo/bar/`. It will not work with `/foo/bar` (this should never happen as we have special Redirect rule to add trailing slash) as well as with longer URLs like `/foo/bar/meow/` -- you would need to duplicate and modify last 2 lines.

Also, if there is a folder that matches URL (e.g. `foo/bar/`) then rule will not work as well.

These rules were tested and confirmed to be working. Let me know if you need any modifications.